# Cant Connect SQL Server to Crystal Report 8.5

Tags: sql-server, vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I have 2 Databases with different credentials..
i try to connect the first database and it was successfully added and 
i tried the second database but unfortunately failed.
it says `"General SQL Server error: Check messages from SQL Server."`

what are the possible reason why it failed..

Thanks.

Comment: Ummm, maybe check the error log in SQL Server?

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: how would i do this? i'm connection Crystal Reports to SQL Server

Comment: Here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: no logs showing related to the issue

Comment: I assume you have checked that you can connect to the database using SSMS?

Comment: where could i check this?

Comment: Try to connect to the second using SSMS, it will show you the error

Comment: no problem when using SSMS..

Comment: You show no code at all.  How is the report implemented via VB6?  API?  ActiveX?  The answer is probably going to require a change to the report or the VB6 code if the connection info has changed.

Comment: i have not use vb6 yet... ive just create new report then add the database

Comment: Search for the file SQLSrv.err file on your hard disk.  You should find it in the Crystal directectory under your windows directory.  Open it in your preffered text editor and it should have the errors in it.